# Talend / Snowflake - issue with merge into request

Tags: java, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I'm trying to write a request (for Snowflake) using the MERGE INTO function and I can't use the tDBOutput component with the UPSERT action. I used an example query to see how I should write the template and I got this :

```
MERGE INTO "DEV_MDM_SOFINORD"."MDM"."GROUPE" T USING "GROUPE_20230607_150953_864_1" AS S ON T."CD_GROUPE" = S."CD_GROUPE"  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET  T."CD_GROUPE"=S."CD_GROUPE", T."AT_SIGNATAIRE"=S."AT_SIGNATAIRE" WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT("CD_GROUPE","AT_SIGNATAIRE") VALUES(S."CD_GROUPE" , S."AT_SIGNATAIRE")
```

I don't understand what the "GROUPE_20230607_150953_864_1" is and what it does.

I'm using Talend Cloud API Services Platform (v7.3.1)

It's just a test job but here is the configuration of the components :

[image]

[image]

So I would like to know what `USING "GROUPE_20230607_150953_864_1"` is or if there is an alternative to the MERGE INTO.